# Using tab separation in linux/vim

Tags: tabs, delimited

I am having trouble with the cut command in linux. So say the original data looks something like this:

```
4567 Harrison Joel Accountant
Mitchell Barbara Admin
3589 Olson Timothy Supervisor
4591 Moore Sarah Dept
```

Note that in row 2, it is missing the value for the first column (so only has three fields instead of four).

When I run the following command:

```
$ awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$8}' data.txt |column -t
```

I get:

```
4567      Harrison  Joel     Accountant
Mitchell  Barbara   Admin
3589      Olson     Timothy  Supervisor
4591      Moore     Sarah    Dept
```

What I would like is this:

```
4567  Harrison  Joel     Accountant
      Mitchell  Barbara  Admin
3589  Olson     Timothy  Supervisor
4591  Moore     Sarah    Dept
```

In other words, I want the columns to stay consistent after I perform the tab separation. So it's clear which column corresponds to first name, last name, description, etc.

Is there a good way to do this?